# How can I get return primitive of String array "String[]" in mybatis

Tags: java, spring

I want to get `String[]` from the mybatis as a result

### but result is as follow.

> Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for
>   com.aa.project.dao.homeDao.getHomeDaoROWID
>
> sqlsession.selectOne(nameSpace + ".getTicketHomeDaoROWID");

**java**

```
String[] row = {};
row = homeService.getHomeServeiceROW();

@Service
public String[] getHomeServeiceROW() {
  return homeDao.getHomeDaoROW();
}

@Repository
public String[] getHomeDaoROW() {
  return sqlsession.selectOne(nameSpace + ".getHomeDaoROWID");
}
```

**mapper.xml**

```
<select id="getHomeDaoROWID" resultType="java.util.Map">    
  SELECT AAID
  FROM AAS
</select>
```

in my oracle sqldeveloper
AAID is column name where contains A1, A2, A3, A4, A5 each tuple

I expect the ouput of row = {A1, A2, A3, A4, A5};
but error message is as follows

#### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for com.aa.project.dao.homeDao.getHomeDaoROWID

#### Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for com.aa.project.dao.homeDao.getHomeDaoROWID]을

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for com.aa.project.dao.homeDao.getHomeDaoROWID

Comment: what is the type of your column?

Comment: *"How can I get return primitive of String array"* Strings are not *primitives* and arrays are not *primitives*, so that title doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The type of column is varchar2

Comment: @Andreas this is a Important information for me Thank you. I'm thinking about that

Comment: @Steve if type of column is `varchar`, then how do you expect return type as `String[]` in your `getHomeDaoROW()`?

Comment: `resultType="java.util.Map"` and the column type `varchar` maybe here you have to search answer

Comment: I will try that right now, sir!

Comment: This is the Answer
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.TooManyResultsException: Expected one result (or null) to be returned by selectOne(), but found: 6

Comment: so I finally try to change return type String[] into List<String> and resultType="String", and success!
BUT I wanted the result of your way @catscoolzhyk

Comment: and I'm tyring but not easy

Comment: Meaning the "but found 6" in the above Error message, there are 6 tuples in my database